# XNA - Copies of Same Source Model

Tags: c#, reference, xna, instance, 3d-model

If I do this:

```cs
Model test1 = content.Load<Model>(@"Models/floorTile");
Model test2 = content.Load<Model>(@"Models/floorTile");
Model test3 = content.Load<Model>(@"Models/floorTile");

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in test1.Meshes)
    foreach (Effect effect in mesh.Effects)
        ((BasicEffect)effect).DiffuseColor = Color.Red.ToVector3();
```

all three models will be assigned the color red, not just test1.

This is a simplified version of my problem, in the real version, I am using an actual HLSL effect, and while I know how to clone the single effect to work on multiple unique fbxs, I am not sure how to create more than one instance of a 3dmodel and assign each it's own texture, instead of them all referencing one texture/effect and therefore every "floorTile" in my scene will always look the same.

The only workaround I can think of is to create a different floortile fbx model for each model, but I have a lot of tiles, so that would be far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think is something like this:

```cs
foreach (var mesh in Model.Meshes)
{
   foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
   {
       effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
       effect.TextureEnabled = true;
       effect.Texture = modelTexture;
       effect.Projection = Camera.Projection;
       effect.View = Camera.View;
       effect.World = AbsoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * FinalWorldTransforms;
    }
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

You can have more than one `Model` (like Model1, Model2 and Model3) and different `modelTexture` to apply on them.
As you can see this uses `BasicEffect`, I don't know if can be useful if you're using HLSL.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see what you're saying, and it would work without BasicEffects, It's true that within each draw call, I can swap the color and get different colors for the same model,

but if i have 30 squares and all are different colors, that would mean i would have to swap textures 30 times each draw call, even if the actual color for the square never changes color. I'm hoping there is still a better way than that.

Comment: I hope so, but I haven't too much experience with 3D and Effects to help you.

Comment: The texture swapping is less relevant than the fact that you are performing 30 draw calls in one frame, when you could combine them. This takes optimization in how you build your scene, though. Without that extra optimization, this solution is the standard way to do things like this: you typically don't copy the entire model, but just draw it in a *different way*.

Comment: Really? It seems like so much work in Draw, if I had 30 different fbx models, i could assign them all a texture on creation then my draw would just be (foreach model) draw();, but since they are the same model, you're saying I have to go through and swap the texture in and 30 times a frame, even though nothing in the scene is actually changing textures?